# AngularJS filter data based on JSON records

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sorting, angularjs-scope

I have a JSON file and want to print `<divs>` based upon address of resturants but I want to group them based upon the 'r.Address' field. Like all records with 'Address' Delhi should show first followed by all records of 'Chandigarh' and so on. How can I do this?

Following is some of my code

```
                    <a href="#" ng-repeat="r in resturant" id="rest-list-f" class="offVal">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered form-planner-inner">
                            <span class="form-text">{{ r.Name }}</span><br>
                            <address><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;{{ r.Address }}</address>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ r.Image }}" alt="{{ r.Name }} Image"><br>
                            <hr/>
                            <table class="eventActive">
                                <caption><strong><center><a href="#">Click To Read Reviews</a></center></strong></caption>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;{{ r.Type }}</td>
                                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;{{ r.Hours }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </a>
```

This is my JSON Code

```
   {
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Sagar Ratna",
      "Image": "./images/sr.jpg",
      "Address": "Mohali",
      "Type": "South Indian",
      "Hours" : "10:00-23:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "The Night Factory",
      "Image": "./images/nf.jpg",
      "Address": "Chandigarh",
      "Type": "Chinese",
      "Hours" : "24/7"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Whistling Duck",
      "Image": "./images/ed.jpg",
      "Address": "Rajpura",
      "Type": "Chinese",
      "Hours" : "11:30-23:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Uncle Jack's",
      "Image": "./images/uj.jpg",
      "Address": "Mohali",
      "Type": "Pizza",
      "Hours" : "10:00-22:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Corner Griller",
      "Image": "./images/cg.jpg",
      "Address": "Rajpura",
      "Type": "North Indian",
      "Hours" : "11:00-23:30"
    },    {
      "Name": "Starbucks",
      "Image": "./images/st.jpg",
      "Address": "Delhi",
      "Type": "Coffee",
      "Hours" : "24/7"
    }
  ]
}
```

This the output I want like :

```
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Delhi </div>
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Mohali </div>
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Mohali </div>
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Rajpura </div>  
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Rajpura </div>
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Rajpura </div>
<div> Restaurant Name, Address: Chandigarh </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed a bit in your code. please try this.

**JSON**

```
  $scope.Restaurents =  {
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Sagar Ratna",
      "Image": "./images/sr.jpg",
      "Address": "Mohali",
      "Type": "South Indian",
      "Hours" : "10:00-23:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "The Night Factory",
      "Image": "./images/nf.jpg",
      "Address": "Chandigarh",
      "Type": "Chinese",
      "Hours" : "24/7"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Whistling Duck",
      "Image": "./images/ed.jpg",
      "Address": "Rajpura",
      "Type": "Chinese",
      "Hours" : "11:30-23:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Uncle Jack's",
      "Image": "./images/uj.jpg",
      "Address": "Mohali",
      "Type": "Pizza",
      "Hours" : "10:00-22:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Corner Griller",
      "Image": "./images/cg.jpg",
      "Address": "Rajpura",
      "Type": "North Indian",
      "Hours" : "11:00-23:30"
    },    {
      "Name": "Starbucks",
      "Image": "./images/st.jpg",
      "Address": "Delhi",
      "Type": "Coffee",
      "Hours" : "24/7"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Html**

```
<a href="#" ng-repeat="r in Restaurents.records | orderBy:'Address'" id="rest-list-f" class="offVal">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-centered form-planner-inner">
                    <span class="form-text">{{ r.Name }}</span><br>
                    <address><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;{{ r.Address }}</address>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ r.Image }}" alt="{{ r.Name }} Image"><br>
                    <hr />
                    <table class="eventActive">
                        <caption><strong><center><a href="#">Click To Read Reviews</a></center></strong></caption>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;{{ r.Type }}</td>
                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;{{ r.Hours }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Hope it will help.
also you can group json array while processing in controller side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy filter of `angular.filter` module.
so you can do something like this:

**usage:** collection | groupBy:property
use nested property with dot notation: `property.nested_property`

**JS:**

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
 Group name: {{ key }}
  <li ng-repeat="player in value">
   player: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

**RESULT:**

Group name: alpha

- player: Gene

Group name: beta

- player: George
- player: Paula

Group name: gamma

- player: Steve
- player: Scruath